# Correlations - Get values in the way we want

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics, python, correlation

I have :

- a matrix X with N lines
- a vector Y

I've computed the Euclidean distance with Y for each line of X.

What I get is a vector of distances.

What I want is a vector of scores between 0 and 1, 1 meaning "very" high correlation, 0 meaning "no" correlation.

Here what I did :

I divided the vector of distances by the max distance inside it.
I get vector D.

*1 - D* is the final result with values between 0 and 1.

The problem is that I get many values (75%) too close to 1.
Do you think what I did is correct ?

How would you get a better result ?
(Between 0 and 1 but not everything too close to 1)

For now, I tried to take the square of the result. (To stay between 0 and 1 but to minimize the values)

Here a picture of the distance values I want to turn in a score
[image: distance values I want to turn in a score]

Comment: (A comment.) I think this is a classical manifestation of the [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Distance_functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several kernel functions can serve as similarity functions (=scores). See a list, for example, [here](https://www.otexts.org/1560). You can try several of them and see which suits you the best.

You need something that drops fast at low distances. You can try
$$ score = 1/(1+distance)^2$$
and adjust coefficient in front of distance so that the score fits between 0 and 1
[image]

About your picture: what are axis labels? and what are x-ticks?

Comment: I think that the kernel doesn't space out the values. My values stay together even after applying the kernel. I'm going to add a picture of how my values are.

Answer (score 1):

Use sigmoidal functions to get the best correlational value. Use Octave/MATLAB for processing your matrix using the function.